# MeteorJS 0.9.0 - Allowing links in todo app

Tags: meteor

Trying to work in the capability to add links to my todo list app that I am working on: http://meantodo.meteor.com

I would like to be able to put a link in the new item box up top and have it auto-create the link to the page posted in the box. Is this possible?

Also have found autolinker.js and think that would be helpful? github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js

Using Meteor 0.9.0. Thanks for the help! Let me know if more info is needed!

Oops! Here's the code! https://github.com/meflowers331/todo

Comment: It probably is, but we need to see the code if you want any help...

Comment: Added link to my code via Github and a resource that might be helpful. Thanks and sorry!